# Flutter Health Package (4.3.0) D/FLUTTER HEALTH(21559): Access Denied

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fit, google-fitness-api, flutter-health

User encounters "D/FLUTTER HEALTH(21559): Access Denied!" error after selecting the mail to connect to "Google Fit"
Package for me it's only working in test mode. when I set the project to production mode, it stops working.
do you have a solution for this?
I set the oauth id. I have given the necessary permissions.

OAuth ID Verf:

[image: Ekran Resmi 2022-11-23 23 46 16]

OAuth Scope:

[image: Ekran Resmi 2022-11-23 23 43 19]

Maniesft Permissions:

[image: Ekran Resmi 2022-11-23 23 44 22]

Flutter Permissions:

[image: Ekran Resmi 2022-11-23 23 44 59]
[image: Ekran Resmi 2022-11-23 23 48 14]

I expected it to work in production mode as well as it worked in test mode. But in production mode, after selecting his mail on the "connect to google fit" screen, he gets the Access Denied error.